# Printing the total Char-count

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enter");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        {
            int c;
            while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {
                char cha = (char) c;
                System.out.println(cha);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the following code I am able to read a characters and print it but I am looking for a method that read character in a string word by word including spaces and then I want to print the total count, Any hint please?

Comment: `char[] ch=yourString.toCharArray(); `

Comment: You could form a single string, grab its character array, and iterate.  Or, if memory considerations are in play, you could read one string at a time and then tally.

Comment: Downvoted because you made no attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could read the whole input line convert it to a String and then return the length:

```
System.out.println("Enter");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = input.readLine();
System.out.println("length:"+s.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something to every character within a string you can loop through every char of a string then print the length of it out.

```
    for(char c: stringName.toCharArray()){
     //do what you want with c the character here
     }
   stringName.length() //to get the length of the string
```